# How to Hide un wanted multibale <p> when IF statment is not true?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, drop-down-menu, getelementbyid

I am trying to hide the other *< p >* when they do not satisfy my IF condition. I know how to do that using mutable lines of "document.getElementById('test3').style.display = 'none';". however, I am trying to find a way that I can combine the "none" style to all the unwanted *< p >* in one line if possible. I was looking into document.querySelector but I was not sure of how I can add it to my code.

My Code:
'''

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    
    function dropdownChange(element)  {
        var Likelihood=document.getElementById("Likelihood").value;
        var Impact=document.getElementById("Impact").value;



        if(Likelihood==="LH1" && Impact!== "Select2"){
            if(Impact==="IM1" || Impact==="IM2" || Impact==="IM3" ){
        
                document.getElementById('test1').style.display = 'block'; 
                document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById('test3').style.display = 'none'; 
        
            } 

            else if (Impact==="IM4" || Impact==="IM5") {
                document.getElementById('test2').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('test1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('test3').style.display = 'none'; 


            } 
        }

        else if (Likelihood==="LH2" && Impact!== "Select2") {
            if(Impact==="IM1" || Impact==="IM2"){
                document.getElementById('test3').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('test1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none'; 
            }

            else if (Impact==="IM3" || Impact==="IM4") {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "MODERATE";
            }

            else if (Impact==="IM5") {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "HIGH";
            }

        }


    }
</script>
</head> 
<body>
        <select id ="Likelihood" onchange="dropdownChange(this);">
                <option value="Select1" selected="selected">Select Likelihood</option>
                <option value="LH1">Rarely (1)</option>
                <option value="LH2">Unlikely (2)</option>
                <option value="LH3">Moderately (3)</option>
                <option value="LH4">Likely (4)</option>
                <option value="LH5">Certainly (5)</option>
    </select>

    <select id="Impact" onchange="dropdownChange(this);">
        <option value="Select2" selected="selected">Select Impact</option>
        <option value="IM1">Insignificant (1)</option>
        <option value="IM2">Minor (2)</option>
        <option value="IM3">Moderate (3)</option>
        <option value="IM4">Major (4)</option>
        <option value="IM5">Critical (5)</option>
    </select>

    <div class="w">  
        <p id="test1" style="display:none;">test1</p>
        <p id="test2" style="display:none;">test2</p>
        <p id="test3" style="display:none;">test3</p>   
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

'''
I want to mention that the text I want to be displayed is based on the selection of both menus. Any kind of hint or ideas to get the result I want would be much appreciated.

Comment: `querySelector` won't help you much, because that also only ever selects a maximum of _one_ element. You would need to use `querySelectorAll` - but then you would still have to _loop over_ the elements that returns, to hide each one of them individually. Not really suitable to be stuck into one single line, that - but you could put it into an additional _function_.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using 'querySelectorAll' but it still won't make that big of a change. I thought about using for loop yet I am not sure it that would be the better solution. Thank you tho, I really appreciate it.